# PHP Having trouble with counting 4 data outputs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im trying to get these to count 4 rows and then output a row div i already tried foreach but it didnt work and i think its because the while element but when someone can help me it would be appreciated.

Im trying to get the whole php code after while to count up to 4

on the first output it needs to echo the code below when there are more then 4 elements and hide when there are below 4

```
<div class='row'>
```

and on every 4th output it needs to close the div if there is a 4th one.

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE displaygroup IN (4, 5, 10) ORDER BY displaygroup DESC");    //alleen rank 4 - 5
    while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        echo '<div id="s-eigenaar" style="margin-bottom:5px;">';
        echo '<div class="se-inner" style="background-image: url(', $config_charurl, '?username=', $r->username, '&action=wav&gesture=sml&size=b&direction=3&head_direction=3);"></div>';
        echo '<div id="staff-info">';
        echo $r->username;
        if ($r->displaygroup == 5) {
            echo '<p>Administrator</p>';
        }
        if ($r->displaygroup == 4) {
            echo '<p>Eigenaar</p>';
        }
        if ($r->displaygroup == 10) {
            echo '<p>RadioBeheer</p>';
        }
        echo '</div></div>';
    }
```

Comment: Create a var to sum and count iterations, then use the operator mod(%). $varcount % 4 == 0 then it counted four iterations, do you get me?

Comment: Im not getting you

Comment: Mod returns the left of division, if tthe left of division to four is zero, then that number is a multiple of four.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me (onduidelijk). Providing a sample of the output you want could help us to understand.

Comment: @PierreFrançois Sorry no screenshots possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve this..

```
    $query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE displaygroup IN (4, 5, 10) ORDER BY displaygroup DESC");    //alleen rank 4 - 5
    $count = 0;
    while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        echo '<div id="s-eigenaar" style="margin-bottom:5px;">';
        echo '<div class="se-inner" style="background-image: url(', $config_charurl, '?username=', $r->username, '&action=wav&gesture=sml&size=b&direction=3&head_direction=3);"></div>';
        echo '<div id="staff-info">';
        echo $r->username;
        if ($r->displaygroup == 5) {
            echo '<p>Administrator</p>';
        }
        if ($r->displaygroup == 4) {
            echo '<p>Eigenaar</p>';
        }
        if ($r->displaygroup == 10) {
            echo '<p>RadioBeheer</p>';
        }
        echo '</div></div>';
        $count++;
        if ($count % 4 != 0) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks if u add

 if ($count % 4 != 0){echo '</div>';}

behind it it will not close another div